# Forcing legacy boot

Tags: pxe-boot, bios, uefi

I have a new PC with a reference Intel motherboard and AMI BIOS (5.010 on a LynxPoint-LP chipset motherboard). There is no OEM support, so I'm on my own with this.

I have a PXE network and WDS 2008R2 server that I'm using to deploy a Windows 10 image from. I have several PCs using a Realtek NIC, which PXE boot just fine. The new PCs are using an Intel 82574L NIC and they won't PXE boot. I have the option to select "UEFI: Intel 82574L Gigabit Network Connection" as the first boot device, but when I do, I see the message "Succeed to download NBP file", then it returns to the BIOS (I disabled all other boot devices). Unlike the guy who posted this screenshot: http://get-cmd.com/2015/02/21/sccm2012-r2-failed-to-boot-pxe-mode-nbp-file/, I do not see any information other than "Succeed to download NBP file".

I tried forcing the PC to boot in Legacy mode, but when I select "Legacy only" under CSM Configuration, the NICs not are listed as available boot devices. I also verified that the network port and cable are working correctly.

Looking at Intel's website (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/32209/Intel-82574L-Gigabit-Ethernet-Controller), I don't see any utility for updating the firmware that would improve the situation.

What am I missing here? How can I make the BIOS boot from the NIC in Legacy mode?

Comment: You cant use an ethernet usb dongle for the deployment as a workaround ?

Comment: I haven't thought of that. I'll pick one up tomorrow, but I'd still like to know what the heck is going on.

Comment: http://henkhoogendoorn.blogspot.com/2014/03/pxe-boot-files-in-remoteinstall-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are dealing with a buggy UEFI implementation here.
When you boot in UEFI mode you should check (Wireshark traffic capture) which architecture is really announced by the client and which NBP is really delivered. If an UEFI FW receives a legacy NBP it usually re-boots.

Comment: I have the same problem using u-boot, last message I get is NBP file was downloaded.